# Fetching distinct month names from a column of a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

From my Dates table i want to fetch distinct month names from a particular Date column.How to fetch those distinct month names? thanks in advance. I'm using sql server so answers related to sql server will be appriciated.

ForwhichMonth 
 2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-02

Comment: Post your `Dates` table here

Comment: 2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-02
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-14
2014-04-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like:

```
select distinct datename(month, YourDateColumn) from YourTable
```

Use `datename` function to get the name of the month for a date and then get the distinct list.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `DISTINCT` and `DATENAME`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(month, Column)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17004/0)